# How to fetch list of participants in a twilio conference after joining a new agent

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on Twilio conference call scenario. My code snippet adds a supervisor in a live conference call. Now I want to send Client callsid, Agent callsid and supervisor callsid to front end. Used following code snippet. So according to my scenario three callsid would be returned however, in some cases two call sids are returned. I don't know why but I've handled the situation through if else structure. But facing issue that supervisor sid is always returned with correct value but agentcallsid and clientcallsid are switched in some cases. Need guidance for any alternative method. code snippet is given below.

```
const joinConference = (conferenceSid, supervisorName, callback) => {
  let participantsArray = [];
  client.conferences(conferenceSid)
    .participants
    .create({
      from: '+18xxxxxxxxx',
      to: `client:${supervisorName}`
    })
    .then(participant => {
      const supervisorCallSid = participant.callSid;
      console.log(`Supervisor Call Sid in Join conference is ${supervisorCallSid}`);
      client.conferences(conferenceSid)
        .participants
        .list((error, results) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
          }
            participantsArray = results.map((participantsResult, index) => {
            return {
              [`agent${index}CallSid`]: participantsResult.callSid
            }
          });
          console.log(participantsArray);
          let result = {};
          if (participantsArray.length > 2) {                    
            result = {
              "supervisorCallSid": participantsArray[0].agent0CallSid,
              "clientCallSid": participantsArray[1].agent1CallSid,
              "agentCallSid": participantsArray[2].agent2CallSid
            }
          } else {
                result = {
              "supervisorCallSid": supervisorCallSid,
              "clientCallSid": participantsArray[0].agent0CallSid,
              "agentCallSid": participantsArray[1].agent1CallSid
            }
          }
          callback(result);
        })
    })
    .done();
}
```

The issue is that agentcallsid and clientcallsid positions are changed everytime when the function is called. Is it issue with map.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, you sometimes get the supervisor call sid and sometimes not because your API call is in a race condition with the supervisor joining the conference. I'd rely on the sid that is returned from the call creation API request rather than the list of participants.

Listing participants in the call does not have an implicit order, so you may find that the agent and the caller are switched given different calls. In this case, I'd likely store the agent and caller call sids somehow when the call is started. You can then refer to your record of who is agent and who is caller, rather than reach out to the API.

I don't know much more about your setup, so I can't suggest anything to specifically help your problem. I hope this sets you in the right direction though.